# Get body from ClientResponse in SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm new to spring boot application. I want to get the response from there in string. this is my code.

```
String accessURL = serverURL + "itim/rest/accesscategories";
        RestClient rc4 = new RestClient(ResourceBuilder.getClientConfig());
        Resource r4 = rc4.resource(accessURL);
        r4.cookie(ltpaToken);
        r4.cookie(jsessionid);
        r4.cookie(csrftoken);
        r4.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        ClientResponse resp4 = r4.get();
```

right now i'm doing this:

```
System.out.println(resp4.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(resp4.getStatusType());
        System.out.println(resp4.getHeaders());
```

and i get this responce:

```
200
OK
CaseInsensitiveMultivaluedMap [map=[Cache-Control=no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,Content- 
Language=en-US,Content-Type=application/vnd.ibm.isim-v1+json,Date=Sat, 24 Apr 2021 02:22:32 
GMT,Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT,Pragma=No-cache,Set- 
Cookie=com.ibm.isim.lastActivity=Bj7WAcMo3apevFKD4JoHyr4iKepdA8AVptb3S7eRM5c%3D; Path=/itim; 
Secure; HttpOnly,Set-Cookie=com.ibm.isim.maxInactive=1800; Path=/itim; Secure,Strict- 
Transport-Security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains,Strict-Transport-Security=max- 
age=31536000; includeSubdomains,Transfer-Encoding=chunked,X-FRAME-OPTIONS=SAMEORIGIN]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this, so you can process the JSON response (unless you already have JSON serialization/de-serialization for a POJO set up elsewhere).

```java
JsonNode body = resp4.bodyToMono( JsonNode.class ).block();
```

You could do something simple like this to test.

```java
System.out.println( resp4.bodyToMono( String.class ).block() );
```

Take a look at the documentation for [`ClientResponse`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html) and [`Mono<T>`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) for more details.

Comment: it says Cannot resolve method 'bodyToMono'

Comment: Can you include your imports with your code then please? Which `ClientResponse` are you using?

Comment: im using import org.apache.wink.client.ClientResponse;

Comment: getMessage() returns OK / Found same as getStatusType().  is there an alternative way to get responce from the server ?

Comment: Ok. Have you tried `getEntity(String.class)`?

Comment: yes i've tried it, this is what i get:

org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntity;)V

Answer (score -2):

Use response.getBody() function or simply response.body if you’re using any frontend framework.

Comment: there is no getBody() function. Im workin on SpringBootApplication